# Java - ordered map

Tags: java, treemap

My code is prompting the user for digits between 0 and 100 and then counting how many occurrences of each digit.

**I'm trying to sort my TreeMap in the  following way:**

[image: Output]

This is my code below, and currently, the output is unsorted. I've tried implementing the method from this link, https://beginnersbook.com/2014/07/how-to-sort-a-treemap-by-value-in-java/, but got the following error:

reason: cannot infer type-variable(s) K,V
(argument mismatch; ArrayList cannot be converted to Map)
where K,V are type-variables:
K extends Object declared in method sortByValues(Map)
V extends Comparable declared in method sortByValues(Map)

Any suggestions?

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    ArrayList<Integer> Digits = new ArrayList<>();
    ArrayList<Integer> UniqueDigits = new ArrayList<>();
    System.out.print("Enter digits: ");
    int value;

    do {
        value = input.nextInt();
        if (value > 0 && value < 101) 
            Digits.add(value);
        } while (value != 0);


    Set<Integer> uniqueDigits = new HashSet<Integer>(Digits);
    Map<Integer, Integer> frequencies = new HashMap<Integer, Integer>();
    for (Integer uniqueDigit : uniqueDigits) {
        frequencies.put(uniqueDigit, Collections.frequency(Digits, uniqueDigit));
    }


    // Printing
    for (Integer key : frequencies.keySet()) {

        if (frequencies.get(key) > 1) {
            System.out.println(key + " - " + frequencies.get(key) + " times");
            } else if (frequencies.get(key) == 1) {
            System.out.println(key + " - " + frequencies.get(key) + " time");
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Where does this error occur? Also, your naming is very confusing and inconsistent. You have two variables with the same name: `uniqueDigits` and `UniqueDigits`, which is bound to cause confusion. Stick with camel case.

Comment: Your post says you are using a TreeMap but your code shows you are using a HashMap.  The HashMap.keySet will be in hash-order (actually unspecified order but I'll presume hash-order).  Change the implementation to TreeMap and it will be in key-order which is what you appear to want.

Answer (score 0):

You can use TreeMap

like this:

```
  public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        Map<Integer, Integer> frequencies = new TreeMap<>();
        System.out.print("Enter digits: ");
        int value;
        do {
            value = input.nextInt();
            if (value > 0 && value < 101)
                frequencies.put(Integer.valueOf(value), frequencies.getOrDefault(Integer.valueOf(value), 1) + 1);
        } while (value != 0);

        frequencies.entrySet().stream().sorted(Entry.<Integer, Integer>comparingByValue().reversed())
                .forEach((entry) -> {
                    if (frequencies.get(entry.getKey()) > 1) {
                        System.out.println(entry.getKey() + " - " + entry.getValue() + " times");
                    } else if (frequencies.get(entry.getKey()) == 1) {
                        System.out.println(entry.getKey() + " - " + entry.getValue() + " time");
                    }
                });
    }
```

, output:

```
5 - 5 times
1 - 4 times
6 - 3 times
23 - 3 times
```

Comment: This is entirely wrong; streams are no-ops if you ignore the return type; this line: "frequencies.entrySet().stream().sorted(Entry.comparingByValue());" does nothing. That the output appears to be sorted is coincidence: It's actually sorted on key (1,5,6,23 - that's also sorted).

Comment: No, because I am using `sortred()` and print them, your answer like mine

Comment: Yes, you updated your code after my comment, and then commenting back to try to make it look like you didn't? Creative. But feels a bit evil.

Comment: No, because of the code above what I intended to write

Answer (score 0):

You can't sort a TreeMap by value. I know that answer exists. It's trying to answer a question similar to: "How do I make coffee using a screwdriver?" - it just doesn't make sense to try to answer the question.

A TreeMap sorts itself automatically on key.

That is what it does. It doesn't sort on value and cannot be made to do so without silly hacks.

So, what can you do?

For starters, forget about TreeMap. I think your thinking went: I need a map with some sort of sorting - let me look in the API - oh, there is this TreeMap thing, it mentions sorting - I'll use that. As I covered, TreeMap explicitly means *sort on keys* - if sorting on keys is not what you are looking for, then TreeMap is not what you are looking for. Go with a plain jane good old map.

You can then sort on value by streaming the values of the map, and sorting those:

```
Map<Integer, Integer> map = new HashMap<>();
map.put(1, 10);
map.put(2, 5);
map.put(3, 30);

Comparator<Map.Entry<Integer, Integer>> comparator = Comparator.comparingInt(
    entry -> entry.getValue().intValue()).reversed();
System.out.println(map.entrySet().stream()
    .sorted(comparator)
    .map(entry -> String.format("%d occurs %d times.", entry.getKey(), entry.getValue()))
    .collect(Collectors.joining("\n")));
```

will print what you want.